# image onload doesn't fire inside useEffect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I have below code in my React function which gets called from my useEffect hook post I fetch image data in base64 format from an API. Basically the console log where it says ***"Drawing image...."*** never appears in the console log. I can't even see any error being reported from image.onerror. I am on React 18.2.0. Has anyone came across this? I also noticed that the last statement image.src() where I set the base64 encoded JPEG content also fails with an error **Error: Cannot find module 'data:image/jpeg;base64,undefined'**
My UseEffect() defiantly fetches data correctly as I can see the image in a hidden img HTML element.

```
const handleDraw =  (imageData) => {
    console.log("handleDraw was called");
    const img = document.getElementById("cardImage");
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var factor  = Math.min ( canvas.width / img.width, canvas.height / img.height );
    const image = new Image();
    
    image.onload =  function() {
      console.log("Drawing image....handleDraw was called card content is ", card.content);
      //context.scale(factor, factor);
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, img.width-10, img.height-20);
      //context.scale(1 / factor, 1 / factor);
      context.font = "30px Arial";
      context.fillStyle = "red";
      context.fillText(message, 50, 50);
    };
    image.onerror = function(err) {
      console.log("err", err);
    };
    const imgUrl = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${card.content}`
    
      image.src = require(imgUrl);
    
    
  };
```

Comment: This line `image.src = require(imgUrl);` doesn’t make sense. You should just assign the data URI directly to the source, ie `image.sec = imgUrl`

Comment: Hi also post your useEffect code. where is the card for card.content come from

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useFffect called");

    API.get("/api/cards/GetCardImage/" + cardId, {
      //signal: signal,
    })
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log("Fetched Image data...")
        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log("+++ populating card image");
          setCard(response.data);
        }, 1000);
        handleDraw(response.data);
        console.log("**  CARD : ", response.data);
      }) .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error); });
  }, []);

Answer (score 0):

variable **card** is not defined. that why your it give undefined. please define card.
or
you can simple replace card.content to imageData. just like below this should be work.

const imgUrl = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${imageData}`

Comment: Sorry Ravindra my bad, card is defined as a state variable const [card, setCard] = React.useState([]); which get updated by useEffect when the API returns base64 image data.